# Find & count identical values in a row in a sorted dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I sorted a dictionary by one of the keys, which is date/time. I want to count 8 consecutive matching key values ('artist' and 'album') as 1 album play. Is this possible?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

def change_date(self):

    entries = self.data_to_dict()
    entries.sort(key=lambda x: (x['datetime']), reverse=False)

    for x in entries:
        album = x['artist'], x['album']
        grouped_album = [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(album)]
        print grouped_album
```

The above outputs below. I see it's working almost the way I want it to, but can the groupby take 2 keys and deal with them as 1 element? Or should I avoid the groupby all together?

```
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('The War on Drugs', 1), ('Slave Ambient (Deluxe Edition)', 1)]
[('Arcade Fire', 1), ('Funeral', 1)]
[('Arcade Fire', 1), ('Reflektor', 1)]
[('Arcade Fire', 1), ('The Suburbs', 1)]
[('Tame Impala', 1), ('Lonerism', 1)]
[('Tame Impala', 1), ('Lonerism', 1)]
```

The raw data is formatted like this:

```
[{'album': 'Lonerism', 'song': 'Led Zeppelin (Bonus Track)', 'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:03:00', 'artist': 'Tame Impala'}, {'album': 'Lonerism', 'song': 'Feels Like We Only Go Backwards', 'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:00:00', 'artist': 'Tame Impala'}, {'album': 'The Suburbs', 'song': 'Empty Room', 'datetime': '2014-12-10 07:57:00', 'artist': 'Arcade Fire'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the last 3 lines are ran within a loop, `groupby` only receives a single album each time.

You should drop the inner for (last 4 lines), and do something like this:

First convert `entries` to `albums`:

```
albums = [(x['artist'], x['album']) for x in entries]
```

Then group all the albums together:

```
grouped_albums = [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k,g in groupby(albums)]
```

BTW - dicts are not sorted. What you have is not a dict, but a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew dicts are unordered, but I didn't realize the sort() makes them into tuples.